# Comparing cells from two different worksheets and pasting arranged results onto another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have part of a code where I have two worksheets named "Dia" and "E" and there is a time column in both of the worksheets. I am writing a program that will compare the cells of the two columns to each other and arrange the time in ascending order, which will be placed in a third worksheet named "E_Dia". When I run the code, the code executes the loops but in a very strange fashion. Instead of arranging the time, it first paste all the values of the time cells of the first sheet and then paste the values from the second sheet.

```
Dim i As Long       ' initiating long variable
Dim l As Long
Dim j As Long


j = 2
l = 2

For i = 2 To LastRow_Dia

    Do While ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dia").Cells(i, 4).Value >= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("E").Cells(j, 4).Value

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("E_Dia").Cells(l, 4).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("E").Cells(j, 4).Value
        j = j + 1
        l = l + 1
Loop

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("E_Dia").Cells(l, 4).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dia").Cells(i, 4).Value

        l = l + 1
Next i
```

The desired result example is as follows:
the first 24 rows should have time values from the "E" worksheet as the time in those rows have smaller values. The 25th row should have time value from the "Dia" worksheet but it doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: Are the values sorted to begin with?  You aren't sorting the values in this code....you're looking at sheet dia, putting all values of E in until E is less than dia, then putting dia.  This never sorts the values from either sheet.

Comment: The times are already in ascending order in the Dia and E worksheets. All I have to do is compare the times in the two sheets and whichever is the smallest has to go first into the E_Dia sheet. 

for example the first time of the dia sheet is 13:53:16.059 and the first 24 cells of the E sheet have time less than this. The 24th cell has time of 13:53:17. So technically 13:53:16.059 should go in the 25th cell of E_Dia worksheet but instead its is putting 13:53:17.

Comment: This code worked fine for me (other than in the case that the largest value in either sheet is in "E"...this will stop once the last value of "Dia" is reached regardless of whether there are more in "E").  I think you are confused as to the number of cells that contain values less than 13:53:17.  You state, "The first 24 cells of E have time less than '13:53:16.059'", but then state that the 24th cell has time of '13:53:17".  These statements can't both be true.  If in fact the 24th cell has time '13:53:17', then the first cell in E of '13:53:16.059' would go in to the 24th cell....

Comment: in the combined sheet and the 25th cell in the combined sheet would be '13:53:17' which would represent the 24th cell in sheet E.  Not really sure where the problem is.

Comment: I mean if you want to test what the output should be, copy the whole list from E onto a new sheet, put the whole list from Dia below it, and then use Excel's sort feature.  Compare this to the output of your code.

Comment: sorry my bad. I mistyped. I should also provide more info. Its actually the 25th cell in E, which has a time of 13:53:17, not the 24th. Also the largest value of time which is 13:53:38 is in the E but the diag sheet has more number of cells. The diag sheet has somewhat 400+ time cells whereas the E sheet has only 44.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?  Is the output the same as when you "manually" sort the data?

Comment: thanks your suggestion has given me another approach to the problem. I can easily copy paste the data from the sheets to the third sheet and then sort the entire data in ascending order. This method seems much simpler. thank you.